# How to implement such a custom rollback in Django or DRF?

Tags: django, database, django-rest-framework, transactions, atomic

Out system accesses to a middle platform(I do not know how to call it in English, we call it `中台` in Chinese) which is for authentication like logging in, `JWT` verifying, etc.
Then, We have encoutered questions when it is neccessary to rollback actions because of unexpected program errors. Like code below, the program will crash when running at `1 / 0`, then `AdminPermission.objects.create` can be rolled back, but `do_user_actions` can not, cause it is a RPC function. So, we need to override transaction.atomic or something like this to implement our requirements. But, I do not know how to implement it. Pls give me some suggestions or sample code. Thx a lot.

```py
    @transaction.atomic  # can not rollback remote func call `do_user_actions`
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # call a remote func here to create a admin account.
        user_dict = do_user_actions(query_kwargs=query_kwargs, action='create-admin')  

        user_id = user_dict.get('id')
        permission_code = 'base_permission'
        AdminPermission.objects.create(user_id=user_id, permission_code=permission_code)

        # some unexpected errors, like:
        1 / 0
        
        return Response('success')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `atomic` with the decorator you could use it as a context manager, something like this,

```
with transaction.atomic():
  try:
    # do your stuff
    user_dict = do_user_actions(query_kwargs=query_kwargs, action='create-admin')
    user_id = user_dict.get('id')
    permission_code = 'base_permission'
    AdminPermission.objects.create(user_id=user_id, permission_code=permission_code)
    1/0 # error
  except SomeError: # capture error
    revert_user_actions() # revert do_user_actions
    transaction.set_rollback(True) # rollback
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_424_FAILED_DEPENDENCY) # failure
return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED) # success
```

[Django Docs - Transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic)

UPDATE

As @Gorgine mention in the comment, the documentation don't recommend to handle errors inside `atomic`. Because is always a good idea to follow recomendations, you can put `atomic` inside `try` block. In this case `atomic` block will handle the rollback if an error occur, so you will need to handle the actions that are not rollback by `atomic` in the `except` block. Something like this:

```
try:
  with transaction.atomic():
    # do your stuff
    user_dict = do_user_actions(query_kwargs=query_kwargs, action='create-admin')
    user_id = user_dict.get('id')
    permission_code = 'base_permission'
    AdminPermission.objects.create(user_id=user_id, permission_code=permission_code)
    1/0 # error
except SomeError: # capture error
  revert_user_actions() # revert do_user_actions
  return Response(status=status.HTTP_424_FAILED_DEPENDENCY) # failure
return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED) # success
```

Comment: I just read the doc, and I found it says ```Avoid catching exceptions inside atomic!```.

Comment: You can put `atomic` inside `try` block and revert user actions in `except` block, check update